# binding [row,col] value to a textView

Tags: android, textview, simplecursoradapter

this is my first Android App. and I have problems with choosing the best Adapter for my application 
I have table like the one drawn, I would like to bind specified rows of VALUE column to TextView
my Question is : 1- how can I bind [row 1,col 3] to textView

---

_ID | NODE        | Value

---

1   |link         |google.com

---

2   | description |search

```
 MyDataBase mDB = new MyDataBase(this);
    Cursor cursor = mDB.all(this);

    String[] from = new String[] {mDB.VALUE};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1View1};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main, cursor, from,to );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "view.setTag(Object)" , in your case the view is textview and the object will be a struct probably with row and column information.